# macOS Terminal - using wget and bash- ERROR "Argument list is too long"

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm using `wget` and `bash` to download a number of sequential files from a URL using `{1..####}` but am getting the error: `Argument list is too long`

1. When I run `getconf ARG_MAX` it says `262144` - what is this limit in reference to?
2. What command will increase the argument limit (or can I remove it or set it to infinite?)

Comment: In **Terminal** `getconf ARG_MAX` will show the limit. In **macOS Catalina** it returns: `262144` I do not believe you can set it higher or unlimited, but I'm not 100% sure of that and why I'm posting this as a comment.

Comment: It's set in `syslimits.h` as: `#define ARG_MAX            (256 * 1024) /* max bytes for an exec function */`

Comment: I believe you'll have to run multiple `wget` _commands_ and limit the _range_ of _sequential files_ in each _command_.

Comment: Or just run the loop in bash and call wget for each URL.

Comment: Gotcha. If I break up the files into two sets i.e. {1..100} and {101..200} is there a way to enter one command to run 2 wget functions back-to-back so I don't have to manually enter the second one in after the first finishes? - Also what is the 262144 in reference to, total file size bytes?

Answer (score 3):

1. `ARG_MAX` is the limit (in terms of memory used) on the size of the total argument list + environment variables passed to an executable. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185017/maximum-number-of-bash-arguments-max-num-cp-arguments), and [this more detailed explanation](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/).
2. You can use `xargs` to split a list of arguments into small-enough-to-process groups, but depending on the form of the arguments (and whether they contain various troublesome characters like whitespace, escapes, quotes etc) this can get complicated. One generally safe way to do it is to use `printf '%s\0'` to print the argument list with nulls terminating it, then `xargs -0` to consume the list:

   ```
    printf '%s\0' https://example.com/prefix{1..100}.html | xargs -0 curl -O
   ```

   Note that any arguments that should be passed to each invocation of the utility (like the `-O` in this example) must be included in the `xargs` invocation, not the `printf` arg list. Also, if there are arguments that need to be passed *after* the big list, you need a more complex invocation of `xargs`.

   Also, this may look like it shouldn't work because the huge argument list is still being passed to `printf`, but that's a shell builtin, not a separate executable, so it's handled inside bash itself and the limit doesn't apply.

[BTW, I thought there must be a previous Q&A covering this, but I couldn't find one. If someone else finds a good one, please mark this question as a duplicate.]

Answer (score 3):

When you run

```
wget 'https://example.com/prefix'{1..9999}'.html'
```

the expansion of the `{1..9999}` is done by the shell, resulting in an extremely long list of arguments (run `echo foo{1..10}` to see what happens).

Instead, you can just run

```
for i in {1..9999}; do
    wget 'https://example.com/prefix'${i}'.html'
done
```

or (as a one-liner)

```
for i in {1..9999}; do wget 'https://example.com/prefix'${i}'.html'; done
```

to have the shell handle the loop directly and not in the arguments passed to `wget`. The overall performance of the downloads is limited by the network anyway, so forking and executing 10'000 `wget` processes (instead of just one) doesn't have a noticeable impact.

PS: Replace 9999 with whatever the highest number is, or use something like `{1,7,9,15,22,36}` for specific numbers.

Comment: I'm a total newbie to all of this, do I just type all of that as is at once (replacing my number and url) or are they separate commands?

Comment: @RobertK , You can type it one line at a time pressing **enter** after each line, or as a single line like: `for i in {1..9999}; do wget https://example.com/prefix${i}.html; done`

Comment: perfect thanks! I assume I can still use the wget commands like -e robots=off in there as well if need be?

Comment: @RobertK , RE: "I assume I can still use the wget commands like -e robots=off in there as well if need be?" --  Yes.

Comment: @RobertK If the URL contains any shell metacharacters (like `&` separating parameters), you should put double-quotes around it to keep the shell from getting confused by those. (Single-quotes won't work here, because they'd prevent the variable reference `${i}` from being expanded (so to speak) into its value. (And if there are any literal dollar-signs in the URL, those'll need to be escaped to prevent them from being treated as variable references).

Comment: @user3439894 Okay so I got all the files downloaded. Now, is there a way to keep a command running over and over in the background using the -timestamping command to have it constantly checking for and instantly re-download any of the files that get updated? The # of files and names will not change but the contents of the files will and I need to have the most up to date versions without doing it manually everytime.

Comment: @nohillside is there a way to modify the term in the { } to select only a specific list of files? like if I want to have it get file # 1, 7, 9, 15, 22, 36 etc... I tried it as {1, 7, 9, 15, 22, 36} but that didn't work.